# Error while deploying app

Tags: iphone

I am making a music app.My app runs sucessfully on stimulator but it shows following errors while deploying.I am using iOS 4.1 device.

Can any one help me getting out this errors while deploying.

```
Build ViewTable of project ViewTable with configuration Debug

Ld build/Debug-iphoneos/ViewTable.app/ViewTable normal armv7
cd /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.1
setenv PATH "/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/xcode 3.2.4/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
"/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" -arch armv7 -isysroot "/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk" -L/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/build/Debug-iphoneos "-F/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/../../Desktop/TravelApp backup 2/VisitIrvine_18 Sep 2010/iphonesimulator4.0/System/Library/Frameworks" "-F/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks" "-F/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks" "-F/xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks" -filelist /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/build/ViewTable.build/Debug-iphoneos/ViewTable.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewTable.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.1 -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -o /Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/build/Debug-iphoneos/ViewTable.app/ViewTable

ld: warning: directory '/Users/uttambeldar/Desktop/ViewTable-1-1/../../Desktop/TravelApp backup 2/VisitIrvine_18 Sep 2010/iphonesimulator4.0/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
ld: warning: in /xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: in /xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: in /xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: in /xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
ld: warning: in /xcode 3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFileManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSFileManager in NetworkManager.o
  "_objc_setProperty", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate setSongListArray:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate setViewController:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate setWindow:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[SongInfo setSongUrl:] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo setImage:] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo setName:] in SongInfo.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UINavigationController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-UINavigationController in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      cfstring=http://www.gaasgroup.co.in/Music/SongList.xml in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=Data: %@ in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=%@ in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=No Errors in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=Errors with xmlParser: %@ in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=Error Error Error!!! in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=Table View in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=row Count %d in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=MyIdentifier in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=TableView in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=MainView in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=mp3filepath %@ in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=row= %d in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=P1=====  %@  in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=%@/Annapoorna Stotram.mp3 in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=f1=====  %@  in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=P2=====  %@  in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=%@/Devi Gayatri.mp3 in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=f2=====  %@  in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=HElloooooooo....... in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=%c in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=% in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=%02x in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=*******************Inside XmlDownloadedFromServer %@*******************
 in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=Annapoorna%20Stotram.mp3 in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=VISHNU---%@ in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=Error  in ViewTableViewController.o
      cfstring=SongList in XmlParser.o
      cfstring=Info in XmlParser.o
      cfstring=Processing Element: %@ in XmlParser.o
      cfstring=Processing Value: %@ in XmlParser.o
      cfstring=FilePath is :-%@ in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=Creating new file at path %@ in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=Failed to create new file. in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=error in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring= inside 200 status code for the request is  == %d  in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=check returned string: %@ in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=The cached version is already updated in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring=Local Version is updated no need to update xml ! in NetworkManager.o
      cfstring= Failure occurs... %d  in NetworkManager.o

      cfstring=Unable to delete file: %@ in NetworkManager.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate dealloc] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController dealloc] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[MainView initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:] in MainView.o
      -[MainView setSelected:animated:] in MainView.o
      -[MainView dealloc] in MainView.o
      -[DetailView didReceiveMemoryWarning] in DetailView.o
      -[DetailView dealloc] in DetailView.o
      -[XmlParser initXmlParser] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser dealloc] in XmlParser.o
      -[SongInfo dealloc] in SongInfo.o
      -[NetworkManager dealloc] in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSData in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityIndicatorView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-UIActivityIndicatorView in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSMutableArray in XmlParser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-UIApplication in ViewTableViewController.o
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewTableAppDelegate in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableAppDelegate in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XmlParser in XmlParser.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_XmlParser in XmlParser.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SongInfo in SongInfo.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SongInfo in SongInfo.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NetworkManager in NetworkManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NetworkManager in NetworkManager.o
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewTableAppDelegate in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableAppDelegate in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XmlParser in XmlParser.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_XmlParser in XmlParser.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SongInfo in SongInfo.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SongInfo in SongInfo.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NetworkManager in NetworkManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NetworkManager in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFileHandle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSFileHandle in NetworkManager.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSBundle in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSURL in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate ParseXML:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate ParseXML:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate ParseXML:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate ParseXML:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableAppDelegate ParseXML:] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:foundCharacters:] in XmlParser.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveResponse:] in NetworkManager.o
      -
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
  "_NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust", referenced from:
      _NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust$non_lazy_ptr in NetworkManager.o
     (maybe you meant: _NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSString in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:

  "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSMutableData in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSURLConnection in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSThread in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSURLRequest in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
  "_AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSXMLParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSXMLParser in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRunLoop", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSRunLoop in NetworkManager.o
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o

      -[ViewTableAppDelegate dealloc] in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in 
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController urlEncode:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController DownloadXML:XmlName:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController XmlDownloadedFromServer:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController retainActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController retainActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController retainActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController retainActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController releaseActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController releaseActivityIndicator] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[MainView LabelText:] in MainView.o
      -[MainView ProductImage:] in MainView.o
      -[MainView ProductImage:] in MainView.o
      -[DetailView changeText:] in DetailView.o
      -[DetailView changeImage:] in DetailView.o
      -[DetailView changeImage:] in DetailView.o
      -[XmlParser initXmlParser] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser initXmlParser] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:foundCharacters:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:foundCharacters:] in XmlParser.o
      -[XmlParser parser:foundCharacters:] in XmlParser.o
      -
      -[XmlParser parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] in XmlParser.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo RemoveControlChar] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo dealloc] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo dealloc] in SongInfo.o
      -[SongInfo dealloc] in SongInfo.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager myThreadMainMethod:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager myThreadMainMethod:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager myThreadMainMethod:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager myThreadMainMethod:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager startHTTPConnection] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager urlEncode:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didReceiveData:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSMutableString in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains", referenced from:
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[ViewTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] in ViewTableViewController.o
      -[NetworkManager GetFile:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connection:didFailWithError:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
      -[NetworkManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] in NetworkManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVAudioPlayer in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-UIImage in MainView.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UITableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainView in MainView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSAutoreleasePool in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCharacterSet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-NSCharacterSet in XmlParser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableAppDelegate in ViewTableAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_XmlParser in XmlParser.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SongInfo in SongInfo.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NetworkManager in NetworkManager.o
  "_AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      _simpleSoundDone in ViewTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewTableViewController in ViewTableViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DetailView in DetailView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is ridiculous at present.  If you want help understanding what a specific error message means that's one thing, but just dumping a bunch of output and expecting someone else to play Dr Forensic (without any other information!) is a bit rude.

Comment: not really ridiculous, scroll to see the text a little to the right and you'll see 'file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)' - that's a pretty good starting point :)

Comment: The Answer for this Question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376437/problems-with-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 1):

Run a CLEAN ALL - part of the `Build` menu and then Build again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to link against the simulator versions of the frameworks rather than the device versions.