# Problems with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm new to the iPhone-Development.

I want to play a Sound when an UIButton is tapped. I tried the following:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface JahrenzeitenViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    UIButton *button_PlaySound;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button_PlaySound;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)playSound {

    //[audioPlayer release];
    //audioPlayer = nil;

    NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
    if (audioPlayer == nil) 
        NSLog(@"Error playing sound. %@", [error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
```

If I try to run the App, I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in JahrenzeitenViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I also tried to change the Line

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];
```

to

```
audioPlayer = [audioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];
```

Then I don't get the error above, but its still not playing and i get the DebugMessage from my NSLog in the "playSound"-Method:

> Error playing sound. (NULL)

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add the `AVFoundation` framework to your project. (right-click on your main target then add existing framework).

Comment: Hm, in the .h-File are the imports for that I think (I forgot to post them):
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
Did you mean that?

Answer (score 6):

To add to the other answers.

You should always look at the documentation of a class 'I.e **AVAudioPlayer**. That you are unfamiliar with when you intend to use it. There at the top of the documentation ( Class Reference) for the  the Class, is a table showing what framework the class belongs to:

[image]

Once you know this add the framework to the project. And also import it into the header (.h) file as others have pointed out

Answer (score 4):

thank you, it worked. I didn't know that I have to add the Framework :S

I used the following instructions:

1. In the project navigator, select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
5. Click the '+' button
6. Select your framework

Answer (score 0):

Pls add the AVFoundation framework to your project. And i think you should add `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` along with `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`